# jquery mobile horizontal scroll

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, horizontal-scrolling

I've a problem with jquery mobile and horizontal scroll.

I want to scroll horizontal inside the div "list". In pc browser's everything is ok, but with smartphone when i scroll horizontally the item scroll only a little bit of pixel, so I've to scroll 10-15 times to see the last element!

Here's the code with the css

```css
div#list {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap
}
div.wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: left;
}
div.element {
  display: inline-block;
  ;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  padding: 1em;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3F7137;
  border: 1px solid #79A777;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000;
  cursor: move;
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  transition: 0.5s;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">1</div>
    <div class="element">2</div>
    <div class="element">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">4</div>
    <div class="element">5</div>
    <div class="element">6</div>
    <div class="element">7</div>
    <div class="element">8</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="element">9</div>
    <div class="element">10</div>
    <div class="element">11</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: work ok, at least on chrome &  firefox mobile on android -- https://jsfiddle.net/xrbsbedc/

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery to disable swipe event in the container div works fine also with smartphone!

```
        $(document).ready( function () {
            $("#list").on( "swipeleft", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ScrollPageLeft() });
            $("#list").on( "swiperight", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ScrollPageRight() });
        });
```